# formatting and mounting a 32 TB RAID 50 disk

Tags: partitioning, mount, raid

I want to know how to format a 32 TB drive. What program should I use and what filesystem?
The largest drives I ever had to map before are 2-3 TB and I always used fdisk for formatting. But fdisk is not working for drives larger than 2.1 TB.

I would prefer that the whole volume is mounted as a single logical drive. We need to store large files in it, some may well pass 4TB.

I have an HP ProLiant DL380p Gen8 server in my administration and configured two 1TB disks as a 1TB system drive and ten 4TB disks into a 30 TB drive using RAID 50. I installed Ubuntu Server 12.04.

UPDATE:
I used parted to relabel the partition table to GUID Partition Table (GPT) from msdos which is default for Ubuntu Server 12.04

```
parted /dev/sdb mklabel gpt
```

I then used parted to create an ext4 partition, which I later relabeled to xfs with: mkfs.xfs /dev/sdb1. The rest went smoothly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [GUID Partition Table (GPT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) on such a large disk. In Linux, there are two families of programs that support GPT:

- The libparted library, which is used by `parted`, GParted, and several others, supports both GPT and the older MBR.
- The GPT fdisk family (`gdisk`, `sgdisk`, and `cgdisk`) is a GPT-only tool. It's installed as part of the `gdisk` package in Ubuntu.

In addition, `fdisk` has recently gained GPT support, but even Ubuntu 14.04 uses a version that's old enough that it lacks this support.

As to filesystems, XFS, JFS, and ext4fs can all handle such a big volume. So can Btrfs, but it's so new that I don't think I'd recommend it. Chances are this is a pretty important project, so you should research the differences between these filesystems for *your specific* needs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are others, but the JFS and XFS filesystems will both support the volume and file sizes you need.  Ubuntu has a [Wiki Page on XFS](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XFS) that covers some pros and cons of XFS, one con being that GRUB doesn't support booting off an XFS volume (JFS is supported).  However, I don't imagine you're trying to boot off this RAID.

You can format large systems like that using `parted` and a `gpt` disk label (the `msdos` label supports up to 2 TB, like `fdisk`).  To install `parted` and create a single partition on your RAID (assuming it appears as `/dev/sdb`), run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install parted
parted /dev/sdb
  mklabel gpt
  mkpart
```

Beyond that, follow the prompts and you should be good to go.

To format the volume as XFS, you would run `sudo mkfs.xfs /dev/sdb1`.  Formatting JFS is similar: `sudo mkfs.jfs /dev/sdb1`.  To use JFS, you'll need to make sure `jfsutils` is installed.

Comment: thanks, it helped me solve it. i knew about parted but not about changing the partition table to GPT.